# Restarting Background agent on Boot in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, service, background-process, bootcompleted

As in Android we have Broadcast Receiver which helps us the receive the Boot_Completed broadcast and restart our service.

I am wandering if Windows Phone 8 SDK has something similar for background agent or scheduler task, if we restart a windows phone.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 8 background agents run automatically when you restart Windows. If the work of background agent was enableded (OS settings), then after you restart a Windows background agent starts automatically, it does not require action from you.